# Factorizable partition polynomials

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, ac.commutative-algebra, partitions

Let $p(n)$ denote the number of (unrestricted) integer partition of $n$ which has the product generating function
$$\sum_{n\geq0}p(n)\,x^n=\prod_{j\geq1}\frac1{1-x^j}.$$
On the other hand, for the number of partitions of $n$ with $k$ parts, $p(n, k)$, we may use a two-variable generating function
$$\sum_{n,k\geq0}p(n,k)\,x^nt^k=\prod_{j\geq1}\frac1{1-tx^j}.$$
Define the polynomials $Q_n(t)=\sum_{k\geq0}p(n,k)\,t^k$. Here are the first few such polynomials, for $1\leq n\leq 11$,
\begin{align*}
Q_1(t)&=t \\
Q_2(t)&=t(t+1) \\
Q_3(t)&=t(t^2+t+1) \\
Q_4(t)&=t(t^3+t^2+2t+1) \\
Q_5(t)&=t(t^4+t^3+2t^2+2t+1) \\
Q_6(t)&=t(t^5+t^4+2t^3+3t^2+3t+1) \\
Q_7(t)&=t\mathbf{(t^2+t+1)(t^4+t^2+2t+1)} \\
Q_8(t)&=t(t^7+t^6+2t^5+3t^4+5t^3+5t^2+4t+1) \\
Q_9(t)&=t(t^8+t^7+2t^6+3t^5+4t^4+6t^3+7t^2+4t+1) \\
Q_{10}(t)&=t\mathbf{(t^2+t+1)(t^7+t^5+2t^4+2t^3+3t^2+4t+1)}.
\end{align*}
My intent here is to focus on the "non-trivial" factorizations that appear in $Q_7(t)$ and $Q_{10}(t)$. Hence, I ask:

> **QUESTION.** Are there finitely many or infinitely many non-trivially factorizable polynomials $Q_n(t)$, say over $\mathbb{N}[t]$?

Comment: Up to $n=1000$, only $n \in \{7, 10, 14, 17\}$, all of which are of the form $t(t^2 + t + 1)Q'_n(t)$.

Comment: Thanks for checking this out, Peter.